# Various compilation and linker errors while using constexpr template functions

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr, c++14

The code below implements a dichotomic search to find if a runtime integral value exist in an enum. Because enum are compile time known, the code try to generate the sorted array of the enum values in a constexpr way and have a constexpr compatible find.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// ============================
using std::cout; using std::endl;
constexpr char const * const el = "\n";

// ============================
template < typename T_, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_enum<T_>::value>::type >
std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & os, T_ const & v ) {
    return os << static_cast<typename std::underlying_type<T_>::type>(v)<< " ";
}

// ============================
// Minimum support for a constexpr array because std::array::operator[] lacks constexpr
template <typename T_, size_t N_>
struct Array {
    constexpr size_t size() const { return N_; }

    constexpr T_&       operator[]( size_t i ) { return values_[i]; }
    constexpr T_ const& operator[]( size_t i ) const { return values_[i]; }

    constexpr T_*        begin()       { return values_; }
    constexpr T_*        end()         { return values_+N_; }
    constexpr T_ const * begin() const { return values_; }
    constexpr T_ const * end() const   { return values_+N_; }

    T_ values_[N_];
};

// ============================
// return a sorted copy of the array argument
template <typename T_, size_t N_>
constexpr Array<T_, N_> const_sort( Array<T_, N_> tab ) {
    Array<T_, N_> result{ T_{} };
    for( size_t i{}; i != N_; ++i )
        result[i] = tab[i];

    for( size_t i{}; i != N_-1; ++i ) {
        size_t min {i};
        for( size_t j{ i+1 }; j != N_; ++j ) {
            if( result[j] < result[min] )
                min = j;
        }
        if( min != i ) {
            auto tmp    = std::move( result[i] );
            result[i]   = std::move( result[min] );
            result[min] = std::move( tmp );
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// ============================
// The user has to specialize UnsortedFunc to return an Array<EnumType,N>
template <typename T_>
constexpr auto const UnsortedFunc();

template <typename T_>
constexpr const decltype(UnsortedFunc<T_>()) Unsorted = UnsortedFunc<T_>();

// ============================
template < typename T_ >
constexpr decltype( const_sort( Unsorted<T_> ) ) Sorted = const_sort( Unsorted<T_> );

// ============================
// check for existence of a matching enum member equal to an integral value.
// The user has to feed a specialization of UnsortedFunc with the enum values.
template< typename E_>
constexpr bool Contains( typename std::underlying_type<E_>::type v ) {
    using T = typename std::underlying_type<E_>::type;
    T min = static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[0]);
    T max = static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[Sorted<E_>.size()-1]);
    if ( v < min || max < v )
        return false;

    size_t low {}, high { Sorted<E_>.size() };
    while ( low < high ) {
        size_t mid = (high + low ) / 2;
        if ( v < static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[ mid ]) ) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            if ( !( static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[ mid ]) < v ) )
                return true;
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

template < typename T_ >
void Dump() {
    for( auto & v : Unsorted<T_> )
        cout << v << " ";
    cout << el;

    for( auto & v : Sorted<T_> )
        std::cout << v << " ";
    cout << el;
}

enum class Foo : int { a=5, b=2, c = 8, d = 1, e = 4, f = 9 };
template <> constexpr auto const UnsortedFunc<Foo>() { 
    return Array<Foo,6>{ Foo::a, Foo::b, Foo::c, Foo::d, Foo::e, Foo::f }; 
}
```

By playing with this code in the main function, i can have a lot of different of warnings and errors.

That one compile and link but i had to dump the two arrays first, still with a warning :

```
int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha << __VERSION__ << el;

    for( auto & v : Unsorted<Foo> )
        cout << v << " ";
    cout << el;
    for( auto & v : Sorted<Foo> )
        std::cout << v << " ";
    cout << el;

    constexpr bool b1 = Contains<Foo>(2);
    constexpr bool b2 = Contains<Foo>(10);

    cout << b1 << " " << b2 << el;

    for( int i{}; i != 10; ++i )
        cout << i << " : " << Contains<Foo>(i) << ", ";
}
```

And the output :

```
main.cpp:60:46: warning: variable 'Unsorted<type-parameter-0-0>' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
constexpr const decltype(UnsortedFunc<T_>()) Unsorted = UnsortedFunc<T_>();
                                             ^
main.cpp:64:71: note: used here
constexpr decltype( const_sort( Unsorted<T_> ) ) Sorted = const_sort( Unsorted<T_> );
                                                                      ^
1 warning generated.
4.2.1 Compatible Clang 3.5 (trunk 198621)
5  2  8  1  4  9  
1  2  4  5  8  9  
true false
0 : false, 1 : true, 2 : true, 3 : false, 4 : true, 5 : true, 6 : false, 7 : false, 8 : true, 9 : true,
```

If i remove the two array dump, i have compilation errors, b1 and b2 cannot anymore be evaluated as constexpr expressions :

```
int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha << __VERSION__ << el;

    constexpr bool b1 = Contains<Foo>(2);
    constexpr bool b2 = Contains<Foo>(10);
    cout << b1 << " " << b2 << el;

    for( int i{}; i != 10; ++i )
        cout << i << " : " << Contains<Foo>(i) << ", ";
}
```

With the output :

```
main.cpp:116:20: error: constexpr variable 'b1' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr bool b1 = Contains<Foo>(2);
                   ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:72:28: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
    T min = static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[0]);
                           ^
main.cpp:116:25: note: in call to 'Contains(2)'
    constexpr bool b1 = Contains<Foo>(2);
                        ^
main.cpp:117:20: error: constexpr variable 'b2' must be initialized by a constant expression
    constexpr bool b2 = Contains<Foo>(10);
                   ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:72:28: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
    T min = static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[0]);
                           ^
main.cpp:117:25: note: in call to 'Contains(10)'
    constexpr bool b2 = Contains<Foo>(10);
                        ^
2 errors generated.
```

Last, if i try to dump the arrays with the Dump function, link errors arrive too :

```
int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha << __VERSION__ << el;
    Dump<Foo>();
}
```

With the output :

```
main.cpp:60:46: warning: variable 'Unsorted<type-parameter-0-0>' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
constexpr const decltype(UnsortedFunc<T_>()) Unsorted = UnsortedFunc<T_>();
                                             ^
main.cpp:64:71: note: used here
constexpr decltype( const_sort( Unsorted<T_> ) ) Sorted = const_sort( Unsorted<T_> );
                                                                      ^
main.cpp:60:46: warning: variable 'Unsorted<Foo>' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
constexpr const decltype(UnsortedFunc<T_>()) Unsorted = UnsortedFunc<T_>();
                                             ^
main.cpp:93:21: note: used here
    for( auto & v : Unsorted<T_> )
                    ^
main.cpp:64:50: warning: variable 'Sorted<Foo>' has internal linkage but is not defined [-Wundefined-internal]
constexpr decltype( const_sort( Unsorted<T_> ) ) Sorted = const_sort( Unsorted<T_> );
                                                 ^
main.cpp:97:21: note: used here
    for( auto & v : Sorted<T_> )
                    ^
3 warnings generated.

/tmp/main-22b320.o: In function `void Dump<Foo>()':
main.cpp:(.text._Z4DumpI3FooEvv[_Z4DumpI3FooEvv]+0xc): undefined reference to `_ZL8UnsortedI3FooE'
main.cpp:(.text._Z4DumpI3FooEvv[_Z4DumpI3FooEvv]+0x20): undefined reference to `_ZL8UnsortedI3FooE'
main.cpp:(.text._Z4DumpI3FooEvv[_Z4DumpI3FooEvv]+0x98): undefined reference to `_ZL6SortedI3FooE'
main.cpp:(.text._Z4DumpI3FooEvv[_Z4DumpI3FooEvv]+0xb0): undefined reference to `_ZL6SortedI3FooE'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Bonus question, on the Sorted and Unsorted definition line, if i use const auto instead of decltype :

```
main.cpp:73:49: error: member reference base type 'const auto' is not a structure or union
    T max = static_cast<T>(Sorted<E_>[Sorted<E_>.size()-1]);
                                      ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
main.cpp:77:37: error: member reference base type 'const auto' is not a structure or union
    size_t low {}, high { Sorted<E_>.size() };
                          ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
main.cpp:77:20: error: variables defined in a constexpr function must be initialized
    size_t low {}, high { Sorted<E_>.size() };
                   ^
main.cpp:93:19: error: invalid range expression of type 'const auto'; no viable 'begin' function available
    for( auto & v : Unsorted<T_> )
                  ^ ~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:114:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'Dump<Foo>' requested here
    Dump<Foo>();
    ^
main.cpp:97:19: error: invalid range expression of type 'const auto'; no viable 'begin' function available
    for( auto & v : Sorted<T_> )
                  ^ ~~~~~~
5 errors generated.
```

Comment: You should definitely learn about [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) !

Comment: @hivert Sadly, I was unable to reduce the code sample as it is the interaction of the different sub elements that triggers the errors, everything simpler behaves normally on my tries. And the code sample is self contained to be copy pasted to coliru.

Comment: Trying on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e84936f74e2301e) I got a different behavior that you described...

Comment: The question is tagged clang and c++1y, use it in coliru instead of gcc and default c++11 "clang++ -std=c++1y" http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1d43ada736fb0b7

Comment: With some changes, the following works http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1aa1434261f81dc7

Comment: may be related to bug http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17848

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told by Jarod42, it was related to the [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17848) he found.

With an up to date clang trunk depository ( version 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 3.5 (202594) ), everything is back to normal. I only had to write my own constexpr std::move as the Visual studio headers are not yet C++14 compliant.

Built ok with that command line `clang-cl.exe /GR- -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 /O0 /FA /Wall -Xclang -std=c++1y  main.cpp` :

The final code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
constexpr char const * const el = "\n";

// ============================
// VS2013 do not have constexpr supports in the standard library
namespace std14 {
    template< class T >
    constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& move( T&& t ) {
        return static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t);
    }
}

// ============================
// Minimum support for a constexpr array because std::array::operator[] lacks constexpr
template <typename T_, size_t N_>
struct Array {
    constexpr size_t size() const { return N_; }

    constexpr T_&       operator[]( size_t i ) { return values_[i]; }
    constexpr T_ const& operator[]( size_t i ) const { return values_[i]; }

    constexpr T_*        begin()       { return values_; }
    constexpr T_*        end()         { return values_+N_; }
    constexpr T_ const * begin() const { return values_; }
    constexpr T_ const * end() const   { return values_+N_; }

    T_ values_[N_];
};

// ============================
// return a sorted copy of the array argument
template <typename T_, size_t N_>
constexpr Array<T_, N_> const_sort( Array<T_, N_> tab ) {
    Array<T_, N_> result{ { T_{} } };
    for( size_t i{}; i != N_; ++i )
        result[i] = tab[i];

    for( size_t i{}; i != N_-1; ++i ) {
        size_t min {i};
        for( size_t j{ i+1 }; j != N_; ++j ) {
            if( result[j] < result[min] )
                min = j;
        }
        if( min != i ) {
            using std14::move;
            auto tmp    = move(result[i]);
            result[i]   = move(result[min]);
            result[min] = move(tmp);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// ============================
// The user has to specialize UnsortedFunc to return an Array<EnumType,N>
template <typename T_>
constexpr auto UnsortedFunc();

template <typename T_>
constexpr const decltype(UnsortedFunc<T_>()) Unsorted = UnsortedFunc<T_>();

// ============================
template < typename T_ >
constexpr decltype( const_sort( Unsorted<T_> ) ) Sorted = const_sort( Unsorted<T_> );

// ============================
// check for existence of a matching enum member equal to an integral value.
// The user has to feed a specialization of UnsortedFunc with the enum values.
template< typename E_>
constexpr bool Contains( std::underlying_type_t<E_> v ) {
    using T = std::underlying_type_t<E_>;
    constexpr auto & sorted = Sorted<E_>;
    T min = static_cast<T>(sorted[0]);
    T max = static_cast<T>(sorted[sorted.size()-1]);
    if ( v < min || max < v )
        return false;

    size_t low {}, high { sorted.size() };
    while ( low < high ) {
        size_t mid = (high + low ) / 2;
        if ( v < static_cast<T>(sorted[ mid ]) ) {
            high = mid;
        } else {
            if ( !( static_cast<T>(sorted[ mid ]) < v ) )
                return true;
            low = mid+1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

enum class Foo : int { a = 5, b = 2, c = 8, d = 1, e = 4, f = 9 };
template <> constexpr auto UnsortedFunc<Foo>() { 
    return Array<Foo,6>{ { Foo::a, Foo::b, Foo::c, Foo::d, Foo::e, Foo::f } }; 
}

int main() {
    cout << std::boolalpha << __VERSION__ << el;

    constexpr bool b1 = Contains<Foo>(2);
    cout << b1 << el;

    for( int i{}; i != 10; ++i ) {
        cout << i << " : " << Contains<Foo>(i) << ", ";
    }   
}
```